# MVC different CSS attributes for same component

Tags: css, model-view-controller

In my website i'm using a sidebar. In the Index view, the sidebar appears after some animations but in the other views I want it to appear fixed when the page loads.

I can achieve both sidebars styles separately, but I can't get the two effects at one time as one css seems to overwrite the previous one.

Do you know how could i do this?

Comment: Please post your markup and CSS.

Comment: Can't you just use a different class on the `body` element in each view to apply targeted CSS?

Comment: It's part of the _layout partial view which is present in all views

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is Create two partial views that have their own CSS files that they reference.  What ever styles you want in those partial views will overwrite anything being defined above it.  You should then be able to render your partials based on some criteria.